# Validate the type of data

Tags: ibm-midrange

How to validate data in RPG code like if a field is of char type then how to validate that it should only take alphabets.....

Comment: Using uppercase in the question title is frowned upon...have edited this to reflect to make it nicer.....

Comment: RPG should do the validation for you, if my memory serves me correct, there's a particular column used for validation (a flag) and supply the validating RPG code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can restrict input to arbitrary subset of characters using %check() build-in function. Below is essential fragment of ILE RPG Reference Manual:

%CHECK(comparator : base {: start})

%CHECK returns the first position of the string base that contains a character that does not appear in string comparator. If all of the characters in base also appear in comparator, the function returns 0.

Answer (score 1):

*In general,* data validation should be done in RPG only if the RPG is an external trigger program. But in any case it depends on what data type a field is and what "validation" should be done.

The %CHECK() function can verify whether a character field has only characters that are in a given subset of characters, but that's only a single instance of many possible "validations". Different data types have different categories of validations. The DATE data type is different from basic character fields, and the TIME data type is different from both. The various numeric data types are different from all of those.

Further, data validation often involves semantic content. For example, a field might be restricted to a range or list of values. Or it might involve foreign keys or other relationships to other values.

In order to know the coding for validation, the precise requirements for the specific field need to be known.

In the specific case of 'alphabetic characters in a character field named FLD01, the validation might be:

`if ( %check('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' : FLD01 ) <> 0 ) ;
   SndErrmsg ('FLD01' : ALPHA_FAILED ) ;
endIf ;`

The SndErrMsg() proc might send a message containing the field name, 'FLD01', embedded in text defined by ALPHA_FAILED.

Any other field is likely to have a different "validation".